# How can I get the wave number and wave vector?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, frequency, wavelength

$$\overrightarrow{E} = (-10 \hat x + 4 \hat z) e^{-j(2x+5z)}$$

I recently started to study electromagnetics, but I'm having a hard time following up.

May I ask how to calculate the wave vector $\overrightarrow{k}$
and the wave number, please?

Also, how can I calculate the magnetic field vector in the frequency domain?

I really appreciate your help guys.

**ADDED: Thanks for the comments, guys.**
I noticed these answers.
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/189504/232791
https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/287991/232791

So it seems like the wave vector $\overrightarrow{k}$ is
$$\overrightarrow{E} (r) = \overrightarrow{E_0} e^{j(\overrightarrow{k} \cdot \overrightarrow{r})},
\overrightarrow{k} = k_x \hat{x} + k_y \hat{y} + k_z \hat{z},
\overrightarrow{r} = x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z},
\overrightarrow{k} = -2 \hat{x} + -5 \hat{z}$$
And the wave number, the vector size is
$$k = \frac{w}{v_p},
\overrightarrow{k} = k_x \hat{x} + k_y \hat{y} + k_z \hat{z},
|\overrightarrow{k}| = \sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2}
= \sqrt{(2\pi/\lambda_x)^2 + (2\pi/\lambda_y)^2 + (2\pi/\lambda_z)^2}
$$
equal to $\sqrt{k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2} = \sqrt{29}$, right?

Since $\overrightarrow{E_0} = E_{0_x} \hat{x} + E_{0_y} \hat{y} + E_{0_z} \hat{z} = (-10 \hat x + 4 \hat z)$ has no $y$ dependence, meaning that this must line in the $zx$ plane,

I thought $\overrightarrow{k}$ should be perpendicular to the $zx$ plane.

- Have I correctly got both the wave vector and the wave number?
- "Differentiating and integrating wrt time",
  do you mean I have to apply Faraday's Law
  $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \times \overrightarrow{E} + \frac{\partial \overrightarrow{B}}{\partial t} = 0$?

Or $\overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{E} = 0, \overrightarrow{\nabla} \cdot \overrightarrow{B} = 0$ in free space?

Just like your first comment, I don't see time, nor frequency as well.
May I please ask for help?

Comment: I voted to closed because, as states, this is an obvious assignment problem.

Comment: I don't see time, nor frequency. What is this, a static field? Then, what wave vector?

Comment: @acarturk it’s the phasor form; classic notation from E&M.  The time component is implicit in a time exponential.

Comment: The fact that I cannot see any frequencies around makes it difficult to believe so, but assuming existence of an $\omega$ you can simply say that the exponent in the time dependent $E$ must be $e^{i(\omega t - \mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r})}$ for this to be a wave, or equivalently the exponent in the phasor domain must be $e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}}$

Comment: Differentiating and integrating wrt time and spatial coordinates is easy in phasor domain, so make use of Maxwell's equations to find $B$

Comment: Dear @ZeroTheHero and acarturk. I have edited and I wish to say I'm trying my best to overcome this. I have been working in other fields and got interested in wireless communications. So I have determined to study electromagnetics again. Thanks to you guys, I think I'm getting close to the answer, but I really need one last help from you guys. Thanks for your time.

Comment: 1st: $\vec{k}\cdot\hat{E}=0$, so the wave vector *is* perpendicular to the electric field. 2nd: Yes, apply Faraday's law to $\vec{E}$ and then integrate with respect to time.